# Security of a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security

What security mechanisms exist in Wordpress to ensure that a popular plugin doesn't contain malicious code which for example tries to gain access to the database or make downstream DDOS attacks?

Comment: WordPress provides a number of tools to assist developers in securing their plugins; see the [Plugin Security](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/) pages for a start. Of course it's up to plugin authors to follow the guidelines.

Comment: My question is kind of the reverse. Who stops threat-actors writing really cool plugins (so they are installed many many times), which under the hood do malicious things?

Comment: @AntKutschera first of all, all plugins submitted to the WordPress plugins directory have to be reviewed before they become publicly available. Second thing: all plugins in the plugins directory are open source, which means anyone can check their code.

Comment: Nothing, but there's [a team that checks over every plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#what-happens-after-submission) that goes into the official repo to weed out the bad actors. Also, [developers are expected to write secure, legal, honest code](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#9-developers-and-their-plugins-must-not-do-anything-illegal-dishonest-or-morally-offensive).

Comment: There's also organizations who spend a lot of time checking for WP vulnerabilities and publish databases of known vulnerabilities and which version you need to upgrade to patch. Here's an example: https://wpscan.com/plugins